# PostSharp 1.5 and .Net 4

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, metaprogramming, aop, postsharp

Postsharp is great, but only the 1.5 version is still opensource.  Does it work with .net 4.0?  If not, are there any other good AOP weavers out there?  I'm not interested in the proxy type.

Comment: Why not use the community version of Postsharp 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

PostSharp 1.5 does appear to work with .net 4.0.  I have a [Cache] Attribute working just fine in a .net 4.0 Class Library.  Now, maybe some parts of it don't work, but i haven't hit those.  Gael can you enlighten me here?

That said, the community edition of the latest PostSharp seems like the way to go.  Thank you Gael for providing a commercially usable lite version of this great product.

Comment: See my answer - we're using PostSharp with ASP.NET 4 projects (v1.5.6.629) with no issues!

Answer (score 4):

PostSharp 1.5 will not run on .NET 4.0. There's a discussion of alternatives on http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/alternatives.

Comment: I think its great you have the alternatives listed on your site.  CCI stuffs looks neat.  What are the restrictions on your community version.

Comment: Restrictions on the community edition are listed on: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/purchase/compare. Basically, the community edition is just a little better than OSS alternatives; the professional edition is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with the other answers... We're using PostSharp on some ASP.NET 4 projects at work with no problems!

I don't remember us having to do anything tricky to get this to work, so if you're getting errors, post them here, and maybe we can help.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: This answer was over 4 years ago. We were using an old version IIRC, though we ripped it out of our app a few years ago for a huge host of reasons!

Answer (score 0):

Running PostSharpo 1.5 from VS2010 is not supported but I've managed to make it work but it took some tinkering.
In the .csproj file add the following line:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostSharpUseCommandLine>True</PostSharpUseCommandLine>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This would make PostSharp run until you can upgrade to a newer and better version.